# Linq to entity - create group by many to many and many to one , child properties by user choice

Tags: linq, group-by, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I have tried to make this work with expression trees but I have not succeeded. To make this question more manageable, I have made an example database.  First database setup:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Place] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [HousePaintEnum] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Location_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Status_Id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person_Location](
    [Person_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Location_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person_Location] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Person_Id] ASC,
    [Location_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Status](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Maritalstatus] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Healthstatus] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Status] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Location] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Location] ([Id], [Place], [HousePaintEnum]) VALUES (1, N'Mars', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Location] ([Id], [Place], [HousePaintEnum]) VALUES (2, N'Earth', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Location] ([Id], [Place], [HousePaintEnum]) VALUES (3, N'Moon', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Location] ([Id], [Place], [HousePaintEnum]) VALUES (4, N'Moon', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Location] ([Id], [Place], [HousePaintEnum]) VALUES (5, N'Earth', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Location] ([Id], [Place], [HousePaintEnum]) VALUES (6, N'Earth', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Location] ([Id], [Place], [HousePaintEnum]) VALUES (7, N'Mars', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Location] ([Id], [Place], [HousePaintEnum]) VALUES (8, N'Moon', 2)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Location] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Person] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([Id], [Name], [Status_Id]) VALUES (1, N'John', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([Id], [Name], [Status_Id]) VALUES (2, N'Erik', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([Id], [Name], [Status_Id]) VALUES (3, N'Lisa', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([Id], [Name], [Status_Id]) VALUES (4, N'Edward', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([Id], [Name], [Status_Id]) VALUES (5, N'Emma', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([Id], [Name], [Status_Id]) VALUES (6, N'Lars', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([Id], [Name], [Status_Id]) VALUES (7, N'Joe', 5)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Person] OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person_Location] ([Person_Id], [Location_Id]) VALUES (1, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person_Location] ([Person_Id], [Location_Id]) VALUES (1, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person_Location] ([Person_Id], [Location_Id]) VALUES (2, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person_Location] ([Person_Id], [Location_Id]) VALUES (2, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person_Location] ([Person_Id], [Location_Id]) VALUES (3, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person_Location] ([Person_Id], [Location_Id]) VALUES (4, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person_Location] ([Person_Id], [Location_Id]) VALUES (4, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person_Location] ([Person_Id], [Location_Id]) VALUES (5, 5)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Status] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Status] ([Id], [Maritalstatus], [Healthstatus]) VALUES (1, N'Married', N'Bad')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Status] ([Id], [Maritalstatus], [Healthstatus]) VALUES (2, N'Single', N'Good')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Status] ([Id], [Maritalstatus], [Healthstatus]) VALUES (3, N'Unknown', N'Best')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Status] ([Id], [Maritalstatus], [Healthstatus]) VALUES (4, N'Single', N'Bad')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Status] ([Id], [Maritalstatus], [Healthstatus]) VALUES (5, N'Single', N'Unknown')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Status] OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_Status] FOREIGN KEY([Status_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Status] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_Status]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person_Location]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_Location_Location] FOREIGN KEY([Location_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person_Location] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_Location_Location]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person_Location]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_Location_Person] FOREIGN KEY([Person_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person_Location] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_Location_Person]
GO
```

I want to able to make the user choose which columns(selected in array of strings) it should group on, please note that in the example tables above there is a table with many to many relationship. The dynamic to create thoose expression trees that allow the user to select which fields to group on is. I send in an array of which table and which field to group on. See the examples below what I want the user to be able to create in the UI(50 tables with 20 of properties):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT this_.Id) AS y0_, 
       lo.Place AS y1_, 
       lo.HousePaintEnum AS y2_, 
       lo.Place AS y3_, 
       lo.HousePaintEnum AS y4_
FROM Person this_
     INNER JOIN Person_Location pl ON this_.Id = pl.Person_Id
     INNER JOIN Location lo ON pl.Location_Id = lo.Id
GROUP BY lo.Place, 
         lo.HousePaintEnum;
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT this_.Id) AS y0_, 
       lo.Place AS y1_, 
       lo.HousePaintEnum AS y2_, 
       lo.Place AS y3_, 
       lo.HousePaintEnum AS y4_,
       s.Maritalstatus as y5_
FROM Person this_
     INNER JOIN Person_Location pl ON this_.Id = pl.Person_Id
     INNER JOIN Location lo ON pl.Location_Id = lo.Id
     INNER JOIN Status s ON this_.Status_Id=s.Id
GROUP BY lo.Place, 
         lo.HousePaintEnum,
         s.Maritalstatus
```

Any suggestions? Iam out of ideas. I have googled alot and expression trees regarding multiple "group by" seems to be hard to solve. Since I group on child properties. Any suggestions would be greatly appricated . Sadly using Dynamic Linq framework is for the moment not an option.

Comment: Can you upgrade to EF Core? I haven't used it, but 2.1+ supports `GroupBy`... [supported platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/platforms)

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie: Sadly no..

Comment: Add several LINQ query samples. Dynamic grouping is possible, but what to do with aggregates? Or you just need `Count`?